# Does Google Workspace rely on A records in DNS for anything else apart from bare domain redirect?

Tags: dns, subdomain, google-workspace

I manage a small Google Workspace. In the beginning, many years ago, the primary domain was configured to redirect to the `www.` subdomain using the relevant Workspace (back then Google Apps?) feature. The DNS records for the domain feature A records pointing to Google IPs, presumably to facilitate the redirection.

Now, there is a need to use the bare domain for other services, and therefore point A records somewhere else. Just the A records, none of the other records (MX, etc.) need to be changed.

Hence the question: does Google Workspace actually rely on A records for anything else apart from bare domain redirect? Will changing the A records affect bare domain email or other Workspace features?

From my research so far, Google’s own docs[0] admonish:

> Don't change your domain A records if you're using non-Google services with your domain because this will make those services unavailable. Before changing your A records, you should already be hosting your domain's website as a Google Site built in your Google Workspace account. For details, see Set up your "naked" domain address.

[0] https://support.google.com/a/answer/2579934?hl=en

The section appears to imply that there is no reason for A records other than naked domain redirection; hence my question.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the A records on the apex. Workspaces hadn’t shown any error message so far, and Gmail integration appears to keep working (a couple emails went through since).

Open for more knowledgeable answers, though…